# mongon: Find the ID with the highest value in another column

Tags: javascript, mongodb, database

Find the ID(s) with the highest current price.("Currently")

Here is a sample of the data:

```
{
    "_id": "1043817906",
    "Currently": 6.00
}
```

I just know the code

```
db.xxx.aggregate({ $group : { _id:null, max: { $max : "$Currently" }}});
```

In this way, the result is

{ "_id" : null, "max" : 18000 }

But i also want know the "_id" number (with maximum "Currently").

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could sort on `currently` field and return the first document:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {"Currently": -1}},
  {$limit: 1},
  {$project: {max: "$Currently"}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method with **[`limit(1)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit)** and a **[`sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort)** on the field i.e:

```
db.xxx.find().sort({ "Currently": -1 }).limit(1)
```